# how to parse html contents returned as a response from a webserver and show a specific tag value in a combobox in desktop application in vb.net

Tags: html, parsing

i am trying to fetch some data from Url using Httpwebrequest/response, i am getting response which i am showing in a msgbox. It show whole HTML contents.
Now my i want to fetch a specific tag(TD tag) value and show all its value in a combobox in vb.net desktop application.

my code to get response from webserver is :

```
enter code here
```

Imports System.IO

Imports System.Net

Imports System.Xml

Imports System.Text.Encoder

Public Class login

```
Private Sub login_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load


End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    End
End Sub

Private Sub Panel1_Paint(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles Panel1.Paint

End Sub

Private Sub Ok_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Ok.Click
    Dim strId As String = txt_uid.Text
    Dim strPwd As String = txt_pwd.Text
    Dim oEncoder As New System.Text.ASCIIEncoding
    Dim postData As String = "UM_username=" + strId
    postData += ("&UM_password=" + strPwd)


    Dim data As Byte() = oEncoder.GetBytes(postData)
    MsgBox(postData)




    Dim webStream As Stream

    Dim webResponse As String = ""

    Dim req As HttpWebRequest

    Dim res As HttpWebResponse
    Dim Output As String
    'Dim Posit1 As Int32
    'Dim Posit2 As Int32

  req = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/basic_framework/index.php?menu=login&UM_email=" & strId & "&UM_password=" & strPwd)
```

req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        req.KeepAlive = False
        req.Method = "POST"
        res = req.GetResponse()

```
    webStream = res.GetResponseStream()

    Dim webStreamReader As New StreamReader(webStream)
    While webStreamReader.Peek >= 0
        Output = webStreamReader.ReadToEnd()
        RichTextBox1.Text = Output
```

Msgbox(Output)

```
    End While







End Sub
```

End Class

**this code get the response from url and show it in a richtextbox or msgbox
Now i want to get a specific tag value (say, td, option values) and show it in a combobox in my vb.net application form dynamically.It would be needed to parse html content then get that tag value . Please suggest me a way......**
If parsing needed , how to parse html contents to get only specific tag value in a combobox in vb.net form

Answer (score 0):

Well...if you can be sure that your request returns valid XHTML (which is XML indeed), you might be able to use an XPath expression.

Comment: thanks Frank, i am a newbiew to .net, may i know how would i know that the response i am getting is XHTML OR XML

Comment: i have a condition in which my web server have php script and on a particular page a select tag will be there which shows some values in combobox(option), i want to FETCH those values from  SELECT TAG of web server To my windows application form combobox directly in vb.net

Comment: In simple laymen words, suppose a page in website have a select tag and in option it dispays country name. So if i want to show those country name in my desktop application combobox through a URL link. How it will be possible . Please suggest me a way or any desktop application which do the same..

Comment: more accurately, on my website i have a select box where i have some value against option (suppose Country names). so how can i show those values in my desktop application's combo box dynamically  using above code

Answer (score 0):

For the most complicated cases (e.g., an AJAX web-site, etc.) you could use HTMLUnit library with iKVM.